# Given two functions $f$ and $g$, prove that $f=g$ iff dom$f=$ dom $g$ and for every $x\in$ dom $f$, $f(x)=g(x)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Given two functions $f$ and $g$, prove that $f=g$ iff dom$f=$ dom $g$ and for every $x\in$ dom $f$, $f(x)=g(x)$

**Proof:**

Assume $f=g$. Then we have

$$(a_0,b_0)\in f\Rightarrow (a_0,b_0)\in g\wedge(a_1,b_1)\in g\Rightarrow (a_1,b_1)\in f$$
so
$$a_0\in\mbox{dom }f\Rightarrow a_0\in\mbox{dom }g\wedge a_1\in\mbox{dom }g\Rightarrow a_1\in\mbox{dom }f$$
and
$$\mbox{dom }f\subseteq\mbox{dom }g\wedge\mbox{dom }g\subseteq\mbox{dom }f$$
therefore,
$$\mbox{dom }f=\mbox{dom }g$$

Now let $x\in\mbox{dom }f$. Then $\exists y=f(x)\in\mbox{rng }f$ such that $(x,y)\in f$. But if $f=g$, then $(x,y)\in g$.

$$\therefore\forall x\in\mbox{dom }g, f(x)=g(x)$$

Now to show the converse, let $\mbox{dom }f=\mbox{dom }g$ and $\forall x\in\mbox{dom }f$, $f(x)=g(x)$.

Then we have $\forall a_0\in\mbox{dom }f$, $\exists b_0\in\mbox{rng }f$ such that $(a_0,b_0)\in f$. But since $\forall x\in\mbox{dom }f$, $f(x)=g(x)$, we have

$$(a_0,b_0)\in f\Rightarrow(a_0,b_0)\in g$$

Likewise, $\forall a_1\in\mbox{dom }g$, $\exists b_1\in\mbox{rng }g$ such that $(a_1,b_1)\in g$. But again, since $\forall x\in\mbox{dom }f$, $f(x)=g(x)$, we have

$$(a_1,b_1)\in g\Rightarrow(a_1,b_1)\in f$$

Therefore, we have $f\subseteq g$ and $g\subseteq f$, and thus $f=g$.

$\blacksquare$

I'm just looking for proof validation here. Is my argument sound? Thanks in advance.

I'm using the usual set theoretic definition of a function:

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. A function from $A$ to $B$ is a nonempty relation $f\subseteq A\times B$ that satisfies the following two conditions:

Existence - $\forall a\in A$, $\exists b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$.

Uniqueness - If $(a,b)\in f$ and $(a,c)\in f$, then $b=c$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a _definition_ (i.e. that two functions $f$ and $g$ are equal iff they have the same domain $X$, same codomain $Y$, and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ in $X$).

Comment: @SurfaceIntegral: if you are using the usual set-theoretic definition of a function, then it's a theorem not the definition.

Comment: @RobArthan, by "usual set-theoretic definition", are you referring to the one where we associate a function as an ordered triple $(X,Y,G)$ where $X$ is the function's domain, $Y$ is the function's codomain, and $G$ is the graph of the function?

Comment: Is "usual set-theoretic definition" the one in which the codomain is automatically the same thing as the image (i.e., $f(X)$)? My own preference is for a function to be a triple, $(X, Y, R),$ where $R$ (the "rule") is a subset of $X \times Y$ satisfiying a couple of properties that you can infer. With *my* definition, the thing claimed here isn't true at all, for the functions $f:[0, 1] \to [0, 1]: x \mapsto x$ and $g:[0, 1]  \to [0, 2]: x \mapsto x$ are distinct. (The first is surjective; the second is not.)

Comment: @SurfaceIntegral the set-theoretic definition I'm using is "Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. A function from $A$ to $B$ is a nonempty relation $f\subseteq A\times B$ that satisfies the following two conditions: Existence - $\forall a \in A,\exists b\in B$ s.t. $(a,b)\in f$ and Uniqueness - If $(a,b)\in f$ and $(a,c)\in f$, then $b=c$.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes more sense. The definition of "function" that you're using would correspond to my definition of the "graph" of the function (i.e. a certain subset of a certain Cartesian product), in which case RobArthan is right, it is a theorem not a definition.

Comment: @SurfaceIntegral perhaps then OP needs to give more precise definitions? i think the issue here is not really whether the answer to the question is correct but whether the question itself is correct. like usually when we say '$f=g$', i think there's some kind of context there like '$f=g$ on $U$' or something. so i think $f$ and $g$ should be given as $f:A \to B$ and $g: C \to B$. This way the 'only if' direction is kind of a weird question or thing to prove, when we don't even know any relationship between $A$ and $C$

Comment: Thank you Gteal: your definition is the standard set-theoretic definition of a function as a set of pairs. *Pace* SurfaceIntegral and JohnHughes, it is not possible to recover the "codomain" of a function from its set-theoretic representation: the morphisms in the category of sets carry more information than functions in set theory. Sorry if that's not relevant to your question, but it is relevant to the comments.

Comment: @Gteal why don't you say that in your post?

Comment: It seems for the OP, a function is a set such $f$ that (a) each element is an ordered pair and (b) if $\langle x,y\rangle \in f$ and $\langle x,z\rangle \in f$, then $y=z$. On can then (c) define $\operatorname{dom}(f)=\{\,x\mid \langle x,y\rangle\in f\,\}$

Comment: @BCLC I edited the original post with the definition I'm using. I didn't have it originally because I thought it was clear from the context that I was using the set-theoretic definition

Comment: FWIW "$(a_0,b_0)\in f\Rightarrow (a_0,b_0)\in g\wedge(a_1,b_1)\in g\Rightarrow (a_1,b_1)\in f$' can be simply stated as "$(a,b) \in f \iff (a,b)\in g$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is fine, but you are doing more than you need to do in the first part: you are doing the right thing in the second part showing that $f = g$ as sets of pairs if $f$ and $g$ are functions with the same domain that agree on any element of that domain. For the first part, there isn't really anything to prove: if $f = g$, then any property that holds of $f$ also holds of $g$ (because they are the same thing).

Comment: perhaps then OP needs to give more precise definitions? i think the issue here is not really whether the answer to the question is correct but whether the question itself is correct. like usually when we say '$f=g$', i think there's some kind of context there like '$f=g$ on $U$' or something. so i think $f$ and $g$ should be given as $f:A \to B$ and $g: C \to B$. This way the 'only if' direction is kind of a weird question or thing to prove, when we don't even know any relationship between $A$ and $C$

Comment: @BCLC I clarified the definition in the original comment thread

Comment: @Gteal right why didn't you say in the post then?

Comment: @BCLC: the OP is using the standard definition of the concept of function in set theory. Why should he or she need to say more?

Comment: @RobArthan was the definition in the post's original revision?

Comment: I don't think so, but who cares? It's a **standard** definition.